# Dynamics 365 connection with SAP, via plugin, with errors

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, integration, sap-erp

I'm just a junior, and I'm taking care of a support project alone, and with many doubts. I have a plugin made, which connects the dynamics with the SAP system. every occurrence created within the dynamics, automatically has to create a protocol in SAP. Most is working, but in some cases it is not integrating. We have an integration log to track, and the message it gives is "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." What could it be, and how could I check what's happening in real time?

I appreciate any help

---

SERVICE INTEGRATION SAP

```
public class IntegracaoSap
    {
        private object service;

        public string XmlSapRetonro { get; private set; }
        public IntegracaoSap(object provider)
        {
            this.service = provider;
        }
        public string OrganizationName { get; set; }


        private static readonly Regex _tags_ = new Regex(@"<[^>]+?>", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        //add characters that are should not be removed to this regex
        private static readonly Regex _notOkCharacter_ = new Regex(@"[^\w;&#@.:/\\?=|%!() -]", RegexOptions.Compiled);


        public string EnviarProtocolo(Ocorrencia ocorrencia, VariavelAmbiente variavelAmbiente, Email email)
        {
            if (ocorrencia == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ocorrência não informada.");
            }
            var emailAssunto = "";
            var response = String.Empty;
            var msgRetorno = String.Empty;
            var remetente = "Remetente: ";
            var assunto = "Assunto: ";
            var descricaoAssunto = "";
            var modeAssuntoRemetente = "";


            var emailCliente = string.Empty;

            if (email != null)
            {

                if (email.De[0].Type.Equals("account", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var conta = new Conta("", service).ObterPorId(email.De[0].Id);
                    emailCliente = conta.Email;
                }
                else if (email.De[0].Type.Equals("contact", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var contato = new Contato("", service).ObterPor(email.De[0].Id);
                    emailCliente = contato.Email;
                }
                
             
                emailAssunto = Regex.Replace(email.Assunto, @"<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;", string.Empty).Trim();

                modeAssuntoRemetente = remetente + email.De[0].Name + " " + " " + emailCliente + " " + " " + "\n" + assunto + " " + "\n" + emailAssunto;
                
            }
            else
            {
                //pegar email de Contato em Ocorrencia
                

                if(ocorrencia.Cliente.Type.Equals("account",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var conta = new Conta("", service).ObterPorId(ocorrencia.Cliente.Id);
                    emailCliente = conta.Email;
                }
                else if (ocorrencia.Cliente.Type.Equals("contact", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var contato = new Contato("", service).ObterPor(ocorrencia.Cliente.Id);
                    emailCliente = contato.Email;
                }

                descricaoAssunto = Regex.Replace(ocorrencia.Descricao, @"<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;", string.Empty).Trim();

                modeAssuntoRemetente = remetente + ocorrencia.Cliente.Name  + " " + "\n" + emailCliente + " " + "\n" + descricaoAssunto;

              
            }
             modeAssuntoRemetente = GetSubstring(modeAssuntoRemetente);

            string usuario = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_usuario_sap").ToString();

            string senha = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_senha_sap").ToString();


            string P_DESCRIPTION = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                string url = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_url_sap_ocorrencia").ToString();
                string sapStatus = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_sap_pstatus").ToString();
                string processType = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_sap_processtype").ToString();
                string category = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_sap_category").ToString();
                string codeGroup = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_sap_codegroup").ToString();

                WebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
                httpWebRequest.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = variavelAmbiente.ObterValorPor("b2bsac_value_sap").ToString();
                httpWebRequest.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{usuario}:{senha}"));

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    var xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:energiasdobrasil-com-br.URA_PROTOCOLO\">" +
                                       "   <soapenv:Header/>" +
                                       "   <soapenv:Body>" +
                                       "<urn:mt_ura_protocolo>" +
                                         "<IV_BU_PARTNER></IV_BU_PARTNER>" +
                                         "<IV_PROCESS_TYPE>" + processType + "</IV_PROCESS_TYPE>" +
                                         "<IV_DIRECTION>0</IV_DIRECTION>" +
                                         "<IV_CATEGORY>" + category + "</IV_CATEGORY>" +
                                         "<P_STATUS>" + sapStatus +"</P_STATUS>" +
                                         "<P_DESCRIPTION>PROTOCOLO E-MAIL</P_DESCRIPTION>" +
                                         "<P_CODE_GROUP>" + codeGroup + "</P_CODE_GROUP>" +
                                         "<P_CODE>PR01</P_CODE>" +
                                         "<P_FUNC_PARC>ZP000010</P_FUNC_PARC>" +
                                         "<P_FUNC_PARC_RESP>ZP000011</P_FUNC_PARC_RESP>" +
                                         "<P_RESP>CRM_DYN</P_RESP>" +
                                         "<P_DATA>" +
                                            "<REF_GUID></REF_GUID>" +
                                            "<REF_HANDLE></REF_HANDLE>" +
                                            "<REF_KIND></REF_KIND>" +
                                            "<APPT_TYPE></APPT_TYPE>" +
                                            "<TIMESTAMP_FROM></TIMESTAMP_FROM>" +
                                            "<TIMEZONE_FROM></TIMEZONE_FROM>" +
                                            "<TIMESTAMP_TO></TIMESTAMP_TO>" +
                                            "<TIMEZONE_TO></TIMEZONE_TO>" +
                                            "<DATE_FROM>" + ocorrencia.CriadoEm.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "</DATE_FROM>" +
                                            "<DATE_TO>" + ocorrencia.CriadoEm.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "</DATE_TO>" +
                                            "<TIME_FROM>" + ocorrencia.CriadoEm.Value.ToString("hhmmss") + "</TIME_FROM>" +
                                            "<TIME_TO>" + ocorrencia.CriadoEm.Value.ToString("hhmmss") + "</TIME_TO>" +
                                            "<SHOW_LOCAL></SHOW_LOCAL>" +
                                            "<DOMINANT></DOMINANT>" +
                                            "<RULE_ID></RULE_ID>" +
                                            "<RULE_NAME></RULE_NAME>" +
                                            "<DURATION></DURATION>" +
                                            "<TIME_UNIT></TIME_UNIT>" +
                                            "<IS_DURATION></IS_DURATION>" +
                                            "<MODE></MODE>" +
                                         "</P_DATA>" +
                                         "<P_INSTALLATION></P_INSTALLATION>" +
                                         "<P_NOTIFICATION></P_NOTIFICATION>" +
                                         "<P_SALESDOCUMENT></P_SALESDOCUMENT>" +
                                         "<P_OBJECTIVE>011</P_OBJECTIVE>" +
                                         "<P_ATIVIDADE_PREC></P_ATIVIDADE_PREC>" +
                                         "<P_BUT0ID>" +
                                            "<PARTNER></PARTNER>" +
                                            "<TYPE></TYPE>" +
                                            "<IDNUMBER></IDNUMBER>" +
                                         "</P_BUT0ID>" +
                                         "<P_LOCATION></P_LOCATION>" +
                                         "<P_ATIVIDADE_EXTERNA>" + ocorrencia.NumeroOcorrencia + "</P_ATIVIDADE_EXTERNA>" +
                                         "<P_TELEFONE_URA></P_TELEFONE_URA>" +
                                         "<P_TEXTO>" +
                                            "<!--Zero or more repetitions:-->" +
                                            "<item>" +
                                               "<REF_GUID></REF_GUID>" +
                                               "<REF_HANDLE></REF_HANDLE>" +
                                               "<REF_KIND></REF_KIND>" +
                                               "<TDID>A002</TDID>" +
                                               "<TDSPRAS></TDSPRAS>" +
                                               "<LANGU_ISO></LANGU_ISO>" +
                                               "<TDSTYLE></TDSTYLE>" +
                                               "<TDFORM></TDFORM>" +
                                               "<TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>" +
                                               "<TDLINE>" + modeAssuntoRemetente + "</TDLINE>" +
                                               "<MODE></MODE>" +
                                            "</item>" +
                                         "</P_TEXTO>" +
                                      "</urn:mt_ura_protocolo>" +
                                   "</soapenv:Body>" +
                                "</soapenv:Envelope>";
                    streamWriter.Write(xml);
                }

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    msgRetorno = response;
                    this.XmlSapRetonro = response;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msgRetorno = $"Ocorreu um erro no método EnviarProtocolo: {ex.Message}";
            }

            return msgRetorno;
        }
        public static String UnHtml(String html)
        {
            html = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(html);
            html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);

            html = RemoveTag(html, "<!--", "-->");
            html = RemoveTag(html, "<script", "</script>");
            html = RemoveTag(html, "<style", "</style>");

            //replace matches of these regexes with space
            html = _tags_.Replace(html, " ");
            html = _notOkCharacter_.Replace(html, " ");
            html = SingleSpacedTrim(html);

            return html;
        }

        private static String RemoveTag(String html, String startTag, String endTag)
        {
            Boolean bAgain;
            do
            {
                bAgain = false;
                Int32 startTagPos = html.IndexOf(startTag, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                if (startTagPos < 0)
                    continue;
                Int32 endTagPos = html.IndexOf(endTag, startTagPos + 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                if (endTagPos <= startTagPos)
                    continue;
                html = html.Remove(startTagPos, endTagPos - startTagPos + endTag.Length);
                bAgain = true;
            } while (bAgain);
            return html;
        }

        private static String SingleSpacedTrim(String inString)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Boolean inBlanks = false;
            foreach (Char c in inString)
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '\r':
                    case '\n':
                    case '\t':
                    case ' ':
                        if (!inBlanks)
                        {
                            inBlanks = true;
                            sb.Append(' ');
                        }
                        continue;
                    default:
                        inBlanks = false;
                        sb.Append(c);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString().Trim();
        }

        public static string GetSubstring(string modeAssuntoRemetente)
        {
            string valorTexto = modeAssuntoRemetente;

            // Pega os 132 caracteres da String   
            valorTexto = valorTexto.PadRight(132, ' ').Substring(0, 132);
           


            return valorTexto;
        }
    }
}
```

---

OCURRENCE

```
 public class OcorrenciaManager : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            #region Contexto e Serviços
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.  
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            // Obtain the organization service reference which you will need for  
            // web service calls. 
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService adminService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
            IOrganizationService userService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            // Obtain the tracing service
            ITracingService trace = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            #endregion

            adminService.SetDistribution(Distribution.Online);
            Entity entidadeDoContexto = SDKorePlugin.GetContextEntity(context);

            if (SDKorePlugin.Validate(context, SDKorePlugin.MessageName.Create, SDKorePlugin.Stage.PostOperation, SDKorePlugin.Mode.Asynchronous))
            {

                Ocorrencia ocorrencia = entidadeDoContexto.Parse<Ocorrencia>(context.OrganizationName, context.IsExecutingOffline, adminService);

                Email email = new Email(context.OrganizationName, adminService).BuscarPrimeiroEmailOcorrencia(ocorrencia.Id.Value);
                var logIntegracao = new LogIntegracao(context.OrganizationName, adminService);
                var variavelAmbiente = new VariavelAmbiente(context.OrganizationName, adminService);

                trace.Trace("Início da integração de consulta Ocorrencia");


                if (entidadeDoContexto.Attributes.Contains("ticketnumber") && entidadeDoContexto.Attributes.Contains("description"))
                {
                    trace.Trace("Início da integração de consulta Ocorrencia");

                    ocorrencia.CriarXMLParaSap(ocorrencia,variavelAmbiente,email);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

MODEL

```
    [LogicalEntity("incident")]
    public class Ocorrencia : SDKoreBase
    {
        

        #region Construtores
        public IOrganizationService service;

        public Ocorrencia(string organization)
            : base(organization)
        {
            RepositorioOcorrencia = new RepositoryOcorrencia<Ocorrencia>();
        }

        public Ocorrencia(string organization, object provider)
            : base(organization, provider)
        {
            RepositorioOcorrencia = new RepositoryOcorrencia<Ocorrencia>();
            RepositorioOcorrencia.SetOrganization(organization);
            this.SetProvider(provider);
        }

        private void SetProvider(object provider)
        {
            RepositorioOcorrencia.SetProvider(provider);
            this.Provider = provider;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Atributos

        private RepositoryOcorrencia<Ocorrencia> RepositorioOcorrencia { get; set; }

        [LogicalAttribute("customerid")]
        public Lookup Cliente { get; set; }

        [LogicalAttribute("incidentid")]
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }

        [LogicalAttribute("ticketnumber")]
        public string NumeroOcorrencia { get; set; }

        [LogicalAttribute("description")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [LogicalAttribute("b2bsac_integracaoSAP")]
        public Option Sac_Integracaosap { get; set; }

        [LogicalAttribute("emailaddress")]
        public string Email { get; set; }


        #endregion

        #region Métodos

        public Ocorrencia ObterPorNumOcorrencia(string NumeroOcorrencia)
        {
            Ocorrencia _ocorrencia = null;

            _ocorrencia = RepositorioOcorrencia.BuscarPorOcorrencia(NumeroOcorrencia);
            return _ocorrencia;
        }

        public Ocorrencia ObterPor(Guid ocorrenciaId)
        {
            return RepositorioOcorrencia.Retrieve(ocorrenciaId);
        }

        public Guid Criar()
        {
            return RepositorioOcorrencia.Create(this);
        }

        public void Atualizar()
        {
            RepositorioOcorrencia.Update(this);
        }

        public void CriarXMLParaSap(Ocorrencia ocorrencia, VariavelAmbiente variavelAmbiente, Email email)

        {

            string response = string.Empty;
            string MsgError = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var ocorrenciaAtualizar = new Ocorrencia("", this.Provider);
                ocorrenciaAtualizar.Id = ocorrencia.Id;
                ocorrenciaAtualizar.Sac_Integracaosap = new Option((int)Enumerator.IntegracaoSAP.EnviadoParaSap);
                ocorrenciaAtualizar.Atualizar();


                var integracaoSAP = new IntegracaoSap(this.Provider);

                response = integracaoSAP.EnviarProtocolo(ocorrencia, variavelAmbiente, email);

                var logIntegracao = new LogIntegracao("", this.Provider);

                try
                {
                    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

                    xDoc.LoadXml(response);

                    if (xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//P_MSG_RETORNO") != null)
                    {
                        if (xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("P_MSG_RETORNO").Item(0) != null)
                        {
                            MsgError = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("P_MSG_RETORNO").Item(0).InnerText;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((MsgError != "Atividade criada !"))
                    {

                        ocorrenciaAtualizar.Sac_Integracaosap = new Option((int)Enumerator.IntegracaoSAP.NaoIntegradoComSap);

                        ocorrenciaAtualizar.Atualizar();

                        logIntegracao.Mensagem = MsgError;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro))
                        {
                            if (integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro.Length <= 9000)
                            {
                                logIntegracao.Mensagem += integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                logIntegracao.Mensagem += integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro.Substring(0, 8999);
                            }
                        }

                        logIntegracao.NumeroTentativas = 1;

                        logIntegracao.NomeSap = "";

                        logIntegracao.Ocorrencia = new SDKore.DomainModel.Lookup(ocorrencia.Id.Value, "incident");


                        logIntegracao.Criar();



                    }

                    else
                    {
                        ocorrenciaAtualizar.Sac_Integracaosap = new Option((int)Enumerator.IntegracaoSAP.IntegradoComSap);
                        ocorrenciaAtualizar.Atualizar();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ocorrenciaAtualizar.Sac_Integracaosap = new Option((int)Enumerator.IntegracaoSAP.NaoIntegradoComSap);

                    ocorrenciaAtualizar.Atualizar();

                    logIntegracao.Mensagem = ex.Message;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro))
                    {
                        if (integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro.Length <= 9000)
                        {
                            logIntegracao.Mensagem += integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logIntegracao.Mensagem += integracaoSAP.XmlSapRetonro.Substring(0, 8999);
                        }
                    }

                    logIntegracao.NumeroTentativas = 1;

                    logIntegracao.NomeSap = "";

                    logIntegracao.Ocorrencia = new SDKore.DomainModel.Lookup(ocorrencia.Id.Value, "incident");


                    logIntegracao.Criar();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
            }

            
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have the source code of the plugin you can try to replicate the logic inside a console application and triggering the logic on a record that is failing and start from there

Comment: StackOverflow is a help site about programming questions. Could you show your code please?

Comment: Hi, sorry, there is the code...